# Replace word by characters SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the rows where the `concat` of `first_name` and `last_name` has more than 2 words, for example: `Miguel Angel Nieto`, it has 3 words, I've reached that, but the other thing I need to do is to replace all the first words with `'x'`, for example `Miguel` replaced with 5 `'x'`.

`R= 'xxxxx Angel Nieto'`

**TABLE employees**

```
first_name   | last_name
-----------------------
Miguel Angel |  Nieto


SELECT SUBSTR(first_name || ' ' || last_name,
              INSTR(first_name || ' ' || last_name,' ')) AS NOMBRE
  FROM HR.employees 
 WHERE INSTR(first_name || ' ' || last_name,' ',1,2) > 0;
```

Can someone could help me please?

Comment: I got it :)       SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name AS FULLNAME,LPAD(SUBSTR(first_name || ' ' || last_name,INSTR(first_name || ' ' || last_name,' ')),
LENGTH(first_name || ' ' || last_name),'x') AS NAME
FROM HR.employees WHERE INSTR(first_name || ' ' || last_name,' ',1,2) > 0;

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(first_name, '.* ', 'xxxxx ') || ' ' ||last_name as name 
from   employees;
```